# Symfony: Where do I put the code to register a custom MimeTypeGuesser?

Tags: symfony

I need to register a custom MimeTypeGuesser so I can add in some logic to handle .docx files, which my web server's installation of PHP is treating as `application/zip` (which is technically correct). I want it recognized as `application/msword` or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

In the filedoc comment for the class `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType`, there's some info on how to register a custom guesser:

```
 * You can register custom guessers by calling the register() method on the
 * singleton instance. Custom guessers are always called before any default ones.
 *
 *     $guesser = MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance();
 *     $guesser->register(new MyCustomMimeTypeGuesser());
```

Great, but where is an appropriate place for this registration code?

I'd want this to be an app-wide change, but I can't think of a good place to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I myself can't say for sure which place would be appropriate to register custom guesser, so I will simply suggest you one.

Since you're aiming for a app-wide solution, I believe overriding the `build` method of your `Bundle` class would do the trick.

Let's assume your bundle is named `AppBundle`, then your `Bundle` configuration file should be `AppBundle.php` located in `src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php`

Normally that file should be nothing, but an empty class that extends Symfony's core Bundle class - `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle`.

From there you can override the `build` method that we inherit from `Bundle\Bundle` and register your guesser. Normally `build()` is used to register custom extension, such as payment gateways, or compiler passes and stuff like that. You can see that left in comments actually:

```
/**
 * Builds the bundle.
 *
 * It is only ever called once when the cache is empty.
 *
 * This method can be overridden to register compilation passes,
 * other extensions, ...
 *
 * @param ContainerBuilder $container A ContainerBuilder instance
 */
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{

}
```

So, add the following statements at the top of your class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
```

And then simply override the method:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    parent::build($container);

    $guesser = MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance();
    $guesser->register( new MyMimeTypeGuesser() );
}
```

This would load your custom guesser once the application loads all of its bundles. I would like to say that this might not be the perfect solution, but for the time being it can help you.

Comment: I was thinking of using a kernel event listener instead, but this is probably a better solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in `Bundle::boot`:

```
use AppBundle\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MyCustomMimeTypeGuesser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance()->register(new MyCustomMimeTypeGuesser());
    }

    ...

}
```

This will be called every time the `Kernel` boots.

If you do it in `Bundle::build` it would not work, because the call needs to happen at runtime.